# Div not sticking to bottom of the page if I scroll

Tags: html, css

So as the title suggests I have a div that is positioned absolute and has `bottom:0;` but it still will not go all the way down. As you can see here https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAOmn.jpg The footer is at 65% height and looks fine until you shrink the size down then it does not extend.

Basically what i'm asking is how can I make it stay at the bottom of the screen at all times but still only be 65% at the top of the page.

```css
div.bg{
  position:absolute;
  margin:0 auto;
  display:block;
  text-align:center;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  width:100%;
  height:65%;
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  <div class="game bf4"><div class="gametext"><p class="gametext">Battlefield 4</p></div></div>
  <div class="game bf1"><div class="gametext"><p class="gametext">Battlefield 1</p></div></div>
  <div class="game rl"><div class="gametext"><p class="gametext">Rocket League</p></div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you post your html/css code?

Comment: ok I adde me html and css code

Comment: What is the purpose,? to have a fixed footer or something else?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to fix your div to the bottom when you scroll the page, just change its position to `fixed`:

```
div.bg {
  position:fixed;
  ...
}
```

if you have child div's with large heights, try this:

```
div.bg {
  position: absolute;
  display: table; /*display:block;*/
  top:35%; /* instead of height:65%; */
  ...
}

.game{ 
  display: table-row;
  ...
}
```

Comment: That wont work because then the games get stuck too since they are children.

Comment: what are games? you didn't provide their code/css... also it is better to post your images here, i can not open your link

Comment: Basicly the games are divs inside of the bg div that I have to scroll through.

Comment: @mobinblack see edited answer and give your feedback

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
div.bg {
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  left:0;
  height:40vh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`position: absolute;` needs an element to relate the position properties `top`, `right`, `bottom` and `left` to. It will relate to the first ("closest") ancestor element that is *positioned*, which means it does not have `position: static;` which is the default for any block-level element. If it doesn't have any positioned ancestor element, it relates to the `body`.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position):

> `position: absolute;`: Do not leave space for the element. Instead, position it at a specified position relative to its closest positioned ancestor if any, or otherwise relative to the initial containing block.